# Download radio player

Tags: download

The BBC has just changed it's iplayer to a different systems.

I am in Spain and it will not let me download it as it now incorporates TV.

Does anyone know a player I can download?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [Radio Downloader](https://nerdoftheherd.com/tools/radiodld/) could help with this.

[image]